# High, low, deep,?

Tags: antonyms

If a low pitch is the same as a deep tone then what is the equivilant of a high pitch ? Shallow?

I have heard people say high for both but is this correct ?

Comment: I wouldn't use "shallow" for this purpose. (Natural langauges are not 100% symmetrical.)

Answer (score 1):

In music, while "tone" and "pitch" are sometimes synonymous, this is not always the case. A bass viol (aka. double bass) has a low pitch and a deep tone, but a Harp, which is capable of the same low pitches as the double bass, would not be said to have a deep tone. In performing a particular work, if the conductor wanted a less deep tone from a double bass on a low pitch, he might ask for a lighter tone.